# What is the state of Java Beans Binding?

Tags: java, beans-binding

I found an old article http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/beans_binding.html
And a deserted project page http://java.net/projects/beansbinding

Is it still alive? Can I download something? Is there a tutorial?

Comment: Mind explaining, why you are voting to close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though the Beans Binding expert group (JSR-295) never published anything, and the spec is currently listed as inactive.

- http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=295

Answer (score 1):

Beansbinding is available for download in the SVN: http://java.net/projects/beansbinding/sources/svn/show/trunk/beansbinding/src/org/jdesktop?rev=631