# How does BeanProperty.create work?

Tags: java, netbeans, binding, javabeans, frp

I'm trying to get beans binding to work, because it seems like the closest thing to functional reactive programming I can get NetBeans GUI builder to give me.  I'm trying to understand how the code in http://javakenai-dev.cognisync.net/pub/a/2008/03/20/synchronizing-properties-with-beans-binding.html works.  In particular, I'm trying to figure out how the TintedPanel example works.  It seems like BeanProperty.create either has to do voodoo magic, access private fields, or take the string it gets, capitalize the first letter, prepend "get" or "set" to that, and do runtime introspection to change the string into a method it can call.  Can someone point me at complete source code for the TintedPanel example, or explain to me how BeanProperty.create works (preferably with a self-contained working example)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like JSR 295 the beans binding spec is withdrawn:

- https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=295

There are a couple other SO posts with suggestions for other libraries, or pointers to the old beans binding source:

- [What will replace Beans Binding in Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543081/what-will-replace-beans-binding-in-java-7)
- [What is the state of Java Beans Binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720047/what-is-the-state-of-java-beans-binding)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.  It seems that NetBeans still uses beans binding, though...  Is there any way to get something else to integrate with it's GUI?  (I guess I shouldn't care that much about GUI-builder integration...)